# Zxing on iphone: how can i scan qrcode without include zxing widget in my application?

Tags: iphone, zxing

I'm trying to build an augmented reality application for iphone.
I need to scan qrcode but i don't want to add the zxing widget.

Any idea?

Thanks

:)

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this tutorial http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html its easy to integrate zbar into your app. Zbar will automatically pick up either QRCodes or barcodes or you can distinguish which has been scanned. In the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate method the data will be returned as a symbol and as shown in the tutorial, the information stored in the QRCode can be accessed will "symbol.data"

Hope this helps